# Upgrading the old stock GCC in CentOS 5.5 to a current (stable) version

Tags: centos, gcc

What would be the optimal way to do that? Are there any precompiled RPMs available somewhere?

I read [this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/180269/whats-the-preferred-way-of-upgrading-centos-5-5-to-use-the-latest-stable-release), but the answer was not really satisfactory.

The cause for wanting to upgrade: we discovered that the gcc 4.1.2 seems to have issues with some code we need to compile (specifically template stuff) which does not occur with Ubuntu and their newer gcc. We can not simply move to Ubuntu either, because some of the used software depends on CentOS or RedHat.

Any ideas anyone? Should I simply compile it from source into the /opt directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install and use `gcc44` and related packages.

Comment: Oops. Why didn't that show up in yum search gcc... damn. Thanks for the answer!